# How can I become more engaged in a job that is not a good fit and make sure my next job is a better fit?

Tags: work-environment, career-development, job-satisfaction

I work as a PHP developer in a software company. I have 1.5 years of experience, and 0.5 years remain in my company bond period. While in college I was a top performer and was very confident but now 80% of my confidence is gone.

I feel like I don't get any challenging projects. My company has only simple wordpress projects and I don't enjoy that kind of work. I'm afraid that my dream of getting in a good MNC company will get shattered. I worry about whether I will get a competitive salary when I move to a new company and that my skills are getting rusty. I feel like my dreams are shattered.

What can I do at my job to keep my skills fresh despite not getting challenging or engaging projects? What steps should I take to ensure that my next job will be a better fit for my interests?

Comment: Hi, sorry to hear about your situation, it's rough at best. Having said that, it's not very clear what you're asking, and this should likely be closed as off topic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I approach my boss regarding being incredibly bored with my work?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/17055/how-do-i-approach-my-boss-regarding-being-incredibly-bored-with-my-work) and of [Is it unprofessional to fully speak your mind on job satisfaction with your boss or manager?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/17480/is-it-unprofessional-to-fully-speak-your-mind-on-job-satisfaction-with-your-boss)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you have 30-50 work years to do what you are  more interested in . This short-term job is a blip on the road. It may make it take longer to reach your goals, it won't prevent them unless you give up.

Persistence is more important than talent or knowledge in your career. If you let yourself become depressed and give up at every obstacle, then your career won't work out well because every job has obstacles, every life has obstacles.  You have to learn to keep going in spite of them. There are plenty of things you can be doing to reach your goals, you are choosing not to do them. You could be contributing to open source for example. You could be doing persona projects or volunteer software projects for charity. You could be taking classes to keep your skills sharp.  You could be saving your money to buy out your bond early.

If you let depression dictate what you do at work, then you won't be an effective worker and that will harm your career much more than working in a technology you don't like. If you feel that you can't deal with the depression on your own, then get treatment for it.

Comment: There's something more. Depression is not something that can easily be treated with logic and pragmatism. If your mood doesn't improve, go talk to a shrink

Comment: That is why I said that if he felt he couldn't deal with the depression on its own (not all depressed feelings are clinical depression and his sounded more like unrealistic expectations than clinical depression), then he should seek treatment. I have dealt with clinical depression for over 40 years, I know alot about how to work with it and yes not giving in to the depression is part of what you need to learn to do. A profesional psychologist can help you learn to do that, but in the end the only person who can do it is yourself.

Comment: @hlgem , i need motivation and +ve energy . I see my classmates going too high in their careers, unlike me. I hope i will sort out this problem by enjoying my life

Comment: You don't need those things - you want them, there is a huge difference. There will always be people more successful than you and people less successful than you and that has almost nothing to do with whether they are smarter than you or did better in school. Everyone has unique circumstances, comparing yourself to others is a losing proposition. If you are not happy with your current circumstances, take active steps to do something about them.