# how to deny additional responsibilities professionally

Tags: workload

Though am already fed up with many workloads, I'm forced to take up other responsibilities which may take no where professionally.

Am thinking to take this issue to CEO but in a polite way. Request you to help me how I can professionally deny them citing am already held up with many other responsibilities. Also i want to ask am ready to take up additional responsibilities which can professionally take me to next level.

Comment: If you're going to be sending this in English, the first thing to do would be to get a fluent speaker to proofread it.

Comment: You mail should be in fluent English and polite way.

Comment: I'm assuming that the mail needs to be in English?

Comment: see also [How to politely bring up that I need more work](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/33061/how-to-politely-bring-up-that-i-need-more-work)

Answer (score 3):

First, you should be cautioned that limiting yourself to one specific skill set will someday limit your career growth. It's your choice, but most of the happy, successful people I know have evolved throughout their careers.

I recommend the following strategy...

*My plate is very full right now. Is this new assignment important enough to replace one of my other tasks? Which one(s) would you like me to delay while I work on this?*

*I can take on this new assignment, but you should know it's not my strongest skill and I will need a bit of time to get up to speed. Is that ok?*

Hopefully you work in a place where your manager will sit down with you to discuss your performance and career growth. That is the best time to discuss whether your work assignments are in line with your career plans.

Of course, if these assignments are what the company insists it wants you to do, and you don't want to do them, you can always find a job where they want you to do what you like to do. But beware, **every job I've ever seen involves some work that is not fun from time to time.**

Answer (score -3):

Please ignore grammatical mistakes, I wish the tone can be like:

Dear Santhosh,

Am very thankful for the kind of opportunities that you provide me to upgrade my skill set in other verticals. Though am always ready to take-up additional responsibilities, I fear they may deviate me from my professional interests moreover I'm not very keen to develop my skill set in those verticals. I wanna grow vertically in this particular skill set but I never dream to become a jack of all trades.

I also wanna bring to your kind notice that I'm very much involved into my primary responsibilities and i don't find much free time to explore & expertise these works. Request you to kindly look into this issue personally and i believe you will encourage me to increase my skill set in area of my expertise & area of my responsibilities.