# How to fill dead time in work productively

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, productivity, unprofessional-behavior, behavior

Say, you've done your work and asked your boss to review it. But he's really busy and takes hours.

How do you fill that void?

Say you've done everything related to it, like documentation, comments, etc.

What is a good way to kill that time in a productive way?

Comment: Related: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/89603/how-do-i-deal-with-the-30-minutes-remaining-problem/89622#89622 , https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2644/what-can-i-do-at-work-when-i-have-no-work

Comment: VTC - Very Related.  https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/89603/how-do-i-deal-with-the-30-minutes-remaining-problem/89605#89605

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put on some headphones, obscure your screen (so nobody can see what you're doing) and kill it. Bash away at that keyboard tinkering and improving whatever you have built. Heck go the extra mile and build additional features/products. In sum: Take Initiative.

Comment: "So nobody can copy your innovative work and initiative"? Why?

Comment: If you're a programmer, aren't they going to see your work when you commit it, anyway?

Comment: @HerbWolfe Yes, at which point they'll complain about extra review work, unscheduled features, etc!

Answer (score 5):

Got any self training that you can do? Learn new design patterns, how to be a manager, new language, new skills relevant to your job? Don't waste time, train yourself to better yourself. It'll be useful in getting future promotions or new job opportunities.

There are plenty of places that provide online courses allowing you to scratch that educational itch, have a look around and see what takes your interest.

Here are some free examples that I know of (In no particular order). There are plenty more, but might help get you going (I'm not affiliated with any, but have used them in the past):

- https://www.codecademy.com/
- https://www.khanacademy.org/
- https://open.sap.com/courses/
- https://www.udemy.com/

Answer (score 4):

Clean your work area. Gives you something to do and creates a better working environment for yourself. This can also include tidying up your computer file system, organising emails into groups etc,. I've spent more than one productive afternoon on such tasks tidying both my physical and digital workspace.