# Lack of tasks and assignments over a brief period of time

Tags: software-industry, india

**TL, DR;** I don't have much work and it's causing me to feel guilty when I see other people rushing after deadlines. Overall, I'm looking for how to behave in such a situation. Wasting time should cannot be a good answer.

---

I'm currently working as an outsourced employee at a software company in India. I was assigned a project in December '18 and against all expectations of the management, it lasted until the end of July. But my assignation was then extended to mid August. This followed with a couple of weeks of no work. Followed by 2 weeks of re-assignation in the previous project.

Now here's the problem. Despite asking for work (which is rated well as per my manager), I have not been assigned much work (at least in these 2 weeks of assignation). I know that I've been confirmed for another task due to the delay of which I am being left out; but this leaves me feeling anxious (as I am paid above average, and I am not doing half the amount of work my co-workers are).

While I understand that this is none of my business on how the company utilizes me (or under-utilizes me); this leaves a bad impression with my coworkers (coworkers here are other people work in the same office; no one else is currently on my team except me and my manager) as I spend more time on my phone / reading news / doing some online trainings / surfing the net / etc. than doing actual work. Overall I feel guilty coming to office to just sit back, do nothing and take money for it) Not to mention I like learning and training my coding skills.

I've been informed of a knowledge transfer session which might take place by the end of this month. My current assignation ends soon. This hints to no work assignation for another 2 or so weeks.

I've tried to ask my manager a couple of times to assign me something and shared my concerns (minus the impression on coworkers part as I might just be imagining things) and he asked me to be patient. I don't want to continue wasting time. What would be suggested approach?

Comment: Accepted the [duplicate] tag. This post seems to be cloning the linked post. Though a better link would be to https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2644/how-can-i-kill-time-at-work-when-there-is-no-work-for-me-to-do

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the most important thing from your side is to notify your supervisor or manager that you have no tasks to do. As long as they are informed and you have proof that you informed them (mail) you are good and nobody can blame you for anything, nor is it your job to find things to do.

Secondly, if you feel bad about it, I would probably in your place ask my collegues if they need any assistance with their tasks. That way you will be happy because you are doing something, your collegue will be happy because he is getting assistance, and your manager should be happy that you showed incentive to do such a thing from which all have benefit.

Comment: I notified my manager by skype rather than mail. I do have records for that. I do have mails of me asking for more work though. As for the second part, I work on a different technology from them and from what I've seen, no one likes other people meddling in their work. I doubt my manager would care as their project is under different management (My team is me and my manager).